# How to access properties of Uri defined with UriKind.Relative

Tags: c#, uri

My method receives a URI as a string and attempts to parse it into a predictable and consistent format. The incoming URL could be absolute (http://www.test.com/myFolder) or relative (/myFolder). Absolute URIs are easy enough to work with, but I've hit some stumbling blocks working with relative ones. Most notable is the fact that, although the constructor for `Uri` allows you to designate a relative URI using `UriKind.Relative` (or `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`), it doesn't appear to have any properties available when you do this.

Specifically, it throws this exception: `System.InvalidOperationException : This operation is not supported for a relative URI.`

It makes sense that you wouldn't be able to access, say, the `Scheme` or `Authority` properties--although it seems weird that they actually throw invalid operation exceptions instead of just returning blank strings--but even properties like `PathAndQuery` or `Fragment` exhibit the same behavior. In fact, pretty much the only properties that don't throw exceptions for relative URIs are the `IsX` flags and `OriginalString`, which just shows the string you passed in to the the object in the first place.

Given that that constructor explicitly allows you to declare a relative URI, this all seems like a baffling omission. Is there something I'm missing here? **Is there any way to handle relative URIs as their component parts, or do I need to just treat it as a string?** Am I completely failing to understand what "relative URI" means in this case?

To replicate:

```
var uri = new Uri("/myFolder");
string foo = uri.PathAndQuery; // throws exception
```

Visual Studio Pro 2015,
.NET 4.5.2 (if any of that makes a difference)

Answer (score 7):

It's by design that an exception gets thrown when accessing eg. `PathAndQuery` for a relative uri, see [uri source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/URI.cs,870).

As a rather quick and dirty workaround to parse some segments, you could construct a temporary absolute uri out of the relative one, using a dummy base uri (scheme and host) which you ignore.

```
String url = "/myFolder?bar=1#baz";
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://foo.com");
    uri = new Uri(baseUri, uri);
}

String pathAndQuery = uri.PathAndQuery; // /myFolder?bar=1
String query = uri.Query; // ?bar=1
String fragment = uri.Fragment; // #baz
```